# What do all these problem have in common (can't find the origin)?

Tags: views, ajax, theming

A series of problems appeared in my install and I need help to narrow them down to a probable cause.

Most problems come in Views

**1)** All the dropdown menus that group options are gone. Clearing the cache will then display then again for once. Reloading the page again reproduces the issue.
[image]
[image]

**2)** Some block views with ajax/exposed filters are broken: instead of reloading themselves they call the home page with the arguments in the url: `http://www.mysite.com/?field_tags_tid_i18n_op=or&field_tags_tid_i18n=All&status=All`

Again, clearing the cache may solve the issue, but only once

**3)** Here and there, some glitches such as an geofield map not showing in a form until clearing the cache. And again, clearing the cache is only a one time fix as the issue reproduces next time the page is loaded.

I have tried the following:
- Clear the caches (All cache taken indepently work except CSS and Javascript, Theme and tokn regsitry, and update data)
- Clear the content of cache tables directly in mysql
- Remove all performance otions (aggregate css and javascript, cache,...)

Comment: Did you check for any JavaScript errors in browser console? All these give me a hint that you have a error in Javascript.Check your browser console.

Comment: do you use jQuery Update module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was the dhtml-menu module with the "Expand on bullet option"